# Are there any conservative denominations that teach universalism?

Tags: denomination-survey, universalism

When I say “conservative”, I’m thinking along the lines of a church that holds to Biblical Innerancy, the virgin birth, and Trinitarian doctrine. Are there any such denominations that adhere to those things and universalism?